# How do (United States) 529 college savings plans work for attending college in another country?

Tags: international, college, 529-plan

I've been looking into 529 plans for my son (3 yrs old) but he has dual citizenship (US and Canadian).  It is possible that he might attend college in Canada.

I've look around for information on this but did not find any definitive answer.

Does any one know if 529 plans (or any other college saving plans) can be used internationally?

thanks.

Comment: I've read (can't remember where) that the state of Utah offers one of the best 529 plans in the country: great product offerings at low costs. If you have access to the Utah one, it's worth taking a look.

Answer (score 3):

From [Kiplinger](http://www.kiplinger.com/basics/archives/2003/02/529faqs.html#foreign):

> **Can the money be used at a foreign
>   college?** You can use the money at
>   hundreds of foreign colleges,
>   including the University of Toronto,
>   McGill in Montreal and many other
>   Canadian schools. If U.S. students at
>   the school qualify for federal
>   financial aid, you can use 529-plan or
>   ESA money to pay the bills without
>   worrying that you'll lose any of the
>   tax benefits.

Answer (score 2):

The definitive answer -- if you want to call it that -- is in Title 26, Section 529(e)(5):

> (5) Eligible educational institution
> The term “eligible educational
> institution” means an institution-
>
> (A) which is described in section 481 of
> the Higher Education Act of 1965 (20
> U.S.C. 1088), as in effect on the date
> of the enactment of this paragraph,
> and
>
> (B) which is eligible to
> participate in a program under title
> IV of such Act.

[Here's the link](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/html/uscode20/usc_sec_20_00001088----000-.html) to the section mentioned in Part (A).